# How do I use my rails3 generator in all my projects?

Tags: plugins, rubygems, generator, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote a generator that I'd like to use in my Rails3 projects using Thor (which I absolutely love).

How would I go about using my generator in all my rails3 projects?
i.e. how do I install it?

If the answer is to make a gem out of it - could you please describe the rails3 process of doing so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, make a gem!

In terms of loading your generator it's pretty much as simple as putting your generator files in `lib/generators/#{generator_name}/` in the gem. See the [generators guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#generators-lookup) for a little more explanation of how they're loaded.

Check out some gems which do this such as [rails3-generators gem](https://github.com/indirect/rails3-generators). [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails), [machinist](https://github.com/notahat/machinist) for examples.

In terms of actually building your gem, check out [jeweler](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler)

Comment: Awesome! Decided to go with jeweler. Thanks!